# Multiply string in Java

Tags: java, python, string

In  Python I can do this: print("a" * 2);

Output =  aa

Is there a way in Java to do the same without loops?

Comment: Alas no.  Unless you count finding a third party library method that does this by hiding the loop from the caller ;)

Comment: If by loops, you mean a library method, I am sure that method would have a loop implemented in it. There is no other way to do it. So, either way you are using a loop to do it.

Comment: You have to loop, however in Java 8 you could do the looping in a fancy way `IntStream.range(0, 2).forEach(i -> System.out.print("a"));`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String buildString(char c, int n) {
    char[] arr = new char[n];
    Arrays.fill(arr, c);
    return new String(arr);
}
```

`Arrays.fill()` is a [standard API method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28char%5B%5D,%20char%29) that assigns the given value to every element of the given array. I guess technically it'll be looping 'inside', in order to achieve this, but from the perspective of your program you've avoided looping.

Answer (score 3):

While Java does not have a built in method of doing this, you can very easily accomplish this with a few lines of code using a `StringBuilder`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(stringMultiply("a", 2));
}

public static String stringMultiply(String s, int n){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The function `stringMultiply` above does essentially the same thing. It will loop `n` times (the number to multiply) and append the `String` `s` to the `StringBuilder` each loop. My assumption is that `python` uses the same logic for this, it is just a built in functionality, so your timing should not be too much different writing your own `function`.